# ORA-00913 "Too Many Values" Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

This is part of a larger query. Each query works on its own. When I compare the grade in the first query to a constant, ie 50, it also works.

However when I put them together, I get this very unhelpful error message. Oracle SQL's error messages are generally unhelpful, but I can usually muddle my way through to a solution.

This time I don't know what to do since each query works on its own and avg(grade) is a constant just as much as the number 50 is a constant.

If every part works and if the first part works with a different constant while the second part returns a constant, what is the problem?

```
    select stud_id, title, grade
        from uni_enrollment a
        inner join uni_course b
            using (course_id)
        where title = 'Canadian History' and grade 
            > (
                select avg(grade), title
                    from uni_enrollment a
                    inner join uni_course b
                        on a.course_id = b.course_id
                    where title = 'Canadian History'
                    group by (title)                        
                );
```

Okay, thanks to the hint below I've got something that's working. Here, for posterity:

```
    select stud_id, title, grade
        from uni_enrollment a
        inner join uni_course b
            using (course_id)
        where title = 'Canadian History' and grade 
            > (
                select sum(grade)/count(*)
                    from uni_enrollment a
                    inner join uni_course b
                        on a.course_id = b.course_id
                    where title = 'Canadian History'                       
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

This subquery:

```
select avg(grade), title
  from uni_enrollment a
  inner join uni_course b
          on a.course_id = b.course_id
  where title = 'Canadian History'
  group by (title)
```

returns an average **per title**, along **with the title**. This is how your query looks like:

```
... and grade > (select avg(grade), title
```

evaluates to e.g.

```
... and 73 > (50, 'Canadian History'
```

`73` can't be larger than `50, 'Canadian History'` - it can be larger only than `50` alone. Therefore, remove the `title` from subquerie's `select` statement's column list:

```
and grade > (select avg(grade)
             from ...
```

---

> Oracle SQL's error messages are generally unhelpful

Sure they are, but only if you don't know how to interpret them. That's, though,  more your than Oracle's problem.

Comment: Irritatingly, Oracle makes us select any column that we want to group by later. My teacher suggested that other versions of SQL aren't like that. I think I would like that better. Anyway, with your hint I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

The version of Oracle that we're learning in my class forces us to select any column that we want to group by later, and apparently that was what caused my problem. The solution is to rewrite the query without a group by clause. Otherwise it won't work. I hope this got fixed in later versions because it's not so nice.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  I've been using Oracle for a very long time and that has never been a restriction I'm aware of.  It's not a restriction on 11.2 (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=431f5903e054f64658829363d083c1cd) which has been desupported for a while and is 6 or 7 major revisions out of date.

Comment: The *restriction* you hit is that if you use subquery in a comparison predicate, i.e. `grade > (subquery)` the subquery must contain only **one column** - otherwise you get `ORA-00913: too many values`. This is natural and expected and **will not be changed in later versions**, so please edit your answer pointing to this problem and move the correct query there (that you pasted in the question). This is a *high quality* site, so always double check before you write something, otherwise you risc downvotes.

Comment: @mtchk you don't have to select columns that you're grouping by - it's the other way around. And why would you want to select columns that you're not grouping by or aggregating anyway? Just because other flavours of SQL may let you do that doesn't mean that it's right to do so (or, as my mother would say, "just because you can jump off a cliff doesn't mean you should!" ;) ). What would you display in those other columns? Random values? Regardless, I'm pretty sure your original query would fail in those other flavours of SQL too, because what you asked for didn't make sense!